# TinyMCE doesn't work with different areas in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add a `fckeditor` to my MVC project i found this link to do this :`http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget`

Here you can see my model :

```
  public partial class News
    {
        public News()
        {
            this.Images = new HashSet<Image>();
        }

        [DisplayName("متن اصلی خبر")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string NewsText { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("عکس خبرسایز کوچک")]
        public string NewsImageSmall { get; set; }

}
}
```

As you can see one of my attributes `NewsText` needs to use `fckeditor` .I installed the nuget ,after installing the files are added to my project .every thing works fine but the fckeditor doesn't appear in my view ?

here you can see my view part  :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsText, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })

                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsText, new { @class = "form-control myfont" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.NewsText, "", new { @class = "validation" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the final output :
[image]

the error in console :

[image]
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: Hit F12, inspect your browser's console.

Comment: @CodeCaster you mean in my browser?

Comment: a chtml file is created in shared folder ,but i used this fckeditor in a separate area ,does it make any problem ?

Comment: You need to see what your browser tells you. There's probably a 404 somewhere. Once you find the error, you can go from there.

Comment: @CodeCaster the console part shows this error :ncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @CodeCaster i added the picture of the error to my question .could you please take a look

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time for hand-held debugging. It looks like you're missing a Javascript file reference. Show your full (relevant) HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72407/discussion-between-e-a-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing your Screenshot in combination with your error message "`undefined is not a function`"

it seems that `$('#NewsText')` does not exist. This can have two reasons:

1. There is nothing with the id "NewsText" (case sensitive)
2. At this scope that element has not been created yet. Maybe you have to make sure your code is executed after the element is there.

Comment: Thank you ,i think it because of the javascript location but i don't know how can change the address of that

Comment: First right-click onto the text field and select "inspect element" (chrome) or something like that in your browser. Check if the id is "NewsText" or something else.

Comment: OP thinks he has a field with ID "NewsText". You should explain how the HTML helpers work better and why that element doesn't have that ID in his code.

Comment: there MUST be something like <textarea id=NewsText></textarea>. It must be "id" everything else does not matter

Comment: Sorry i finally found that :id="NewsText".